# Printing the Arc and Mutex types

Tags: rust, mutex

How can I print the values of a `Vec` that is encapsulated by a `Mutex` and `Arc`? I'm really new to Rust, so I'm not sure if I am phrasing this well.

This is the code I have, loosely based on the documentation.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![104, 101, 108, 108, 111]));

    for i in 0..2 {
        let data = data.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            let mut data = data.lock().unwrap();
            data[i] += 1;
        });
    }

    println!("{:?}", String::from_utf8(data).unwrap());
    thread::sleep_ms(50);
}
```

The error that the compiler gives me:

> $ rustc datarace_fixed.rs
>   datarace_fixed.rs:14:37: 14:41 error: mismatched types:
>    expected `collections::vec::Vec<u8>`,
>       found `alloc::arc::Arc<std::sync::mutex::Mutex<collections::vec::Vec<_>>>`
>   (expected struct `collections::vec::Vec`,
>       found struct `alloc::arc::Arc`) [E0308]
>   datarace_fixed.rs:14    println!("{:?}", String::from_utf8(data).unwrap());

Answer (score 6):

To work with a Mutex value you have to lock the Mutex, just like you do in the spawned threads. ([playpen](http://is.gd/JHoz04)):

```
let data = data.lock().unwrap();
println!("{:?}", String::from_utf8(data.clone()).unwrap());
```

Note that [String::from_utf8](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8) consumes the vector (in order to wrap it in a String without extra allocations), which is obvious from it taking a value `vec: Vec<u8>` and not a reference. Since we aren't ready to relinquish our hold on `data` we have to `clone` it when using this method.

A cheaper alternative would be to use the slice-based version of [from_utf8](http://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/str/fn.from_utf8.html) ([playpen](http://is.gd/Sdj4Ib)):

```
let data = data.lock().unwrap();
println!("{:?}", from_utf8(&data).unwrap());
```